# Imitate opening a page in a browser so that ajax can run on a server when scheduled as a cron job

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, parallel-processing, server-side

I have scheduled a cron job that runs and its supposed to execute some ajax call but it does not. The page it renders is similar to the one below. i cant execute each script one by one and wait for the responses but because they all keep long, i need to do them asynchronously. When i open this page on my localhost, it renders the html below, runs perfectly and starts the other instances through ajax. But wen i put it on my online server and start it through curl as a cron, the ajax does not run, the page only renders.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/jquery.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>

//execute some php here 



<script>
 var numberOfInstances = "4";
 var userId = ["82372","93823","28372","39823"];

 //Ajax call to url that is supposed to run for each user id
 function startAnotherInstance(i){
    $.ajax({            
                url: "./getreplies.php?instance="+i+"&userid="+userId[i],
                type: 'GET',
                data: null,
                success: function() {

                }
            }); 
    } 


//Initialize the number of instances
 for (i=0;i<numberOfInstances;i++){
    startAnotherInstance(i);
 }
</script>    

</body>
```

Comment: why not just set an interval in js and let that run?

Comment: Where does the page get rendered? Does the machine where this is done have javascript enabled? Could it be that it doesn't like the second `<script>` tag (which doesn't specify language)?

Comment: @flors, the page gets rendered on the server.

Comment: @1337holiday, how do i set an interval, i dont get you

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Javascript engine is built into your browser. CURL does not know what Javascript is.

What you need to write is called a "shell script" that can be initiated with a cron task.